# How to get the best estimator & parameters out from pipelined gridsearch and cross_val_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to find the best parameters from SVC, using nested CV approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC

pipe_svc = make_pipeline(Imputer(),StandardScaler(),PCA(n_components=2),SVC(random_state=1))
param_range = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
param_grid = [{'svc__C': param_range, 'svc__kernel': ['linear']},
              {'svc__C': param_range, 'svc__gamma': param_range,'svc__kernel': ['rbf']}]

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svc,param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy',n_jobs=4, cv = 2)
scores = cross_val_score(gs, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)

scores
# how do I get the best parameters out from gridsearch after cross_val?

Out[]: array([0.925     , 0.9375    , 0.925     , 0.95      , 0.94871795])

gs.best_estimator_

Out[]: Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('imputer', Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)), ('standardscaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), ('pca', PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=2, random_state=None,
  svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)...ar',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=1, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False))])
```

The last line of code only gave 5 accuracy scores. gs.bestestimator_ doesn't yield any useful information either.
What's the best way to combine GridSearchCV with Cross_Val in a pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't have to use `cross_val_score`, you can get all information and meta results during the cross-validation and after finding best estimator.

Please consider this example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
pipe_svc = make_pipeline(Imputer(),StandardScaler(),PCA(n_components=2),SVC(random_state=1))
param_range = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
param_grid = {'svc__C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000], 'svc__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
              'svc__gamma': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]}
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svc,param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv = cv,
                  return_train_score=True)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best Estimator: \n{}\n".format(gs.best_estimator_))
print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(gs.best_params_))
print("Best Test Score: \n{}\n".format(gs.best_score_))
print("Best Training Score: \n{}\n".format(gs.cv_results_['mean_train_score'][gs.best_index_]))
print("All Training Scores: \n{}\n".format(gs.cv_results_['mean_train_score']))
print("All Test Scores: \n{}\n".format(gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score']))
# # This prints out all results during Cross-Validation in details
#print("All Meta Results During CV Search: \n{}\n".format(gs.cv_results_))
```

**Output**

```
Best Estimator: 
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('imputer', Imputer(axis=0, copy=True,
         missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)),
         ('standardscaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, 
         with_std=True)), ('pca', PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', 
         n_components=2, random_state=None,
         svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)...ar',
         max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=1, shrinking=True,
         tol=0.001, verbose=False))])

Best Parameters: 
{'svc__gamma': 0.001, 'svc__kernel': 'linear', 'svc__C': 1}

Best Test Score: 
0.9422110552763819

Best Training Score: 
0.9440783896216558

All Training Scores: 
[0.90012027 0.64070503 0.90012027 0.64070503 0.90012027 0.64070503
 0.90012027 0.64070503 0.90012027 0.64070503 0.90012027 0.64070503
 0.90012027 0.64070503 0.92587291 0.64070503 0.92587291 0.64070503
 0.92587291 0.64070503 0.92587291 0.64070503 0.92587291 0.64070503
 0.92587291 0.64070503 0.92587291 0.64070503 0.93779697 0.68906962
 0.93779697 0.91582382 0.93779697 0.92901362 0.93779697 0.88879951
 0.93779697 0.64070503 0.93779697 0.64070503 0.93779697 0.64070503
 0.94407839 0.91394491 0.94407839 0.93277932 0.94407839 0.93968376
 0.94407839 0.95413931 0.94407839 0.98052483 0.94407839 0.9949725
 0.94407839 0.99937304 0.94533822 0.93090042 0.94533822 0.94345143
 0.94533822 0.94911575 0.94533822 0.96293448 0.94533822 0.99434357
 0.94533822 1.         0.94533822 1.         0.94533822 0.94219554
 0.94533822 0.94219357 0.94533822 0.95099466 0.94533822 0.98052286
 0.94533822 1.         0.94533822 1.         0.94533822 1.
 0.94596518 0.9428225  0.94596518 0.94345537 0.94596518 0.95539323
 0.94596518 0.99371858 0.94596518 1.         0.94596518 1.
 0.94596518 1.        ]

All Test Scores: 
[0.88944724 0.64070352 0.88944724 0.64070352 0.88944724 0.64070352
 0.88944724 0.64070352 0.88944724 0.64070352 0.88944724 0.64070352
 0.88944724 0.64070352 0.92713568 0.64070352 0.92713568 0.64070352
 0.92713568 0.64070352 0.92713568 0.64070352 0.92713568 0.64070352
 0.92713568 0.64070352 0.92713568 0.64070352 0.9321608  0.68090452
 0.9321608  0.90954774 0.9321608  0.92211055 0.9321608  0.84422111
 0.9321608  0.64070352 0.9321608  0.64070352 0.9321608  0.64070352
 0.94221106 0.9120603  0.94221106 0.92713568 0.94221106 0.91959799
 0.94221106 0.93969849 0.94221106 0.81407035 0.94221106 0.65075377
 0.94221106 0.64572864 0.94221106 0.92964824 0.94221106 0.92964824
 0.94221106 0.92462312 0.94221106 0.92211055 0.94221106 0.80653266
 0.94221106 0.65326633 0.94221106 0.64572864 0.94221106 0.92964824
 0.94221106 0.93969849 0.94221106 0.92713568 0.94221106 0.90954774
 0.94221106 0.82663317 0.94221106 0.65326633 0.94221106 0.64572864
 0.93969849 0.94221106 0.93969849 0.93467337 0.93969849 0.92964824
 0.93969849 0.87939698 0.93969849 0.8241206  0.93969849 0.65326633
 0.93969849 0.64572864]
```

Comment: So `cross_val_score` uses `gs.best_params_` ? Meaning uses the best params from grid search

Comment: @yahya I usually do cross validation separately after gridsearch as well for each metric i.e. roc, recall, precision, accuracy. That way I have 4 separate variables for each score I can use in plots after. Is there a way I can save time and have those 4 metrics output at the same time (during GridSearch)? sklearn has the classification report but it doesn't have roc or accuracy only precision and recall.